# Updating $_POST code to php7, isset issue?

Tags: php, mysqli, php-7

I'm getting this error after upgrading to php7, I've solved most issues.

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1

Here's the start of the code (this seems to be causing the issue). When the page is loaded $_POST is not set, there is a drop down (created from sql1), this result feeds into other sql queries later in the script.

```
<?php include 'connect.php'; ?>

<?php
$post_pub = isset($_POST['site']) ?: $_POST['site'] = '';

// Perform queries 
$sql1="SELECT Site_ID, Site_name_1 FROM `Sites` ORDER BY `Sites`.`Site_ID` ASC";
```

Here's the full code

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>

<?php include 'header.php'; ?> 
<div class='container'> 
<?php include 'menu.php'; ?> 
<?php include 'connect.php'; ?>

<?php
$post_pub = isset($_POST['site']) ?: $_POST['site'] = '';

// Perform queries 
$sql1="SELECT Site_ID, Site_name_1 FROM `Sites` ORDER BY `Sites`.`Site_ID` ASC"; 
//$sql1="SELECT Site_ID, Site_name_1 FROM 'Sites' ORDER BY 'Sites'.'Site_ID' ASC"; 

$sqltable1="SELECT Publications.Pub_ID, Publications.ART_TITEL FROM `Publications` where Pub_ID=$post_pub";
$sqltable2="SELECT Aspects.Aspect, Aspect_Pub_join.Pub_ID FROM `Aspects` INNER JOIN `Aspect_Pub_join` ON Aspects.Aspect_ID=Aspect_Pub_join.Aspect_ID WHERE Aspect_Pub_join.Pub_ID=$post_pub"; 
$sqltable3="SELECT Publications.Pub_ID, Questions.Question FROM `Publications` LEFT JOIN `Aspect_Pub_join` ON Publications.Pub_ID=Aspect_Pub_join.Pub_ID LEFT JOIN `Aspect_question_join` ON Aspect_Pub_join.Aspect_ID=Aspect_question_join.Aspect_ID LEFT JOIN `Questions` ON Aspect_question_join.Question_ID=Questions.Question_ID Where Publications.Pub_ID=$post_pub GROUP BY Question ORDER BY Publications.Pub_ID ASC";

$sqltable4="SELECT Publications.Pub_ID, Publications.ART_TITEL FROM `Publications` where Pub_ID=$post_pub"; 
$sqltable5="SELECT Publications.Pub_ID, Publications.ART_TITEL FROM `Publications` where Pub_ID=$post_pub"; 

$result1=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql1) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($mysqli));

$result_table1=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqltable1) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($mysqli));
$result_table2=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqltable2) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($mysqli));
$result_table3=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqltable3) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($mysqli));
$result_table4=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqltable4) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($mysqli));
$result_table5=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqltable5) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($mysqli));



$site_array = array();

while (list($id, $name) = mysqli_fetch_row($result1)) {$site_array[$id] = $name;}


//// Free result set
//mysqli_free_result($result);

function get_options($arr, $current=null) 
{
    $opts = '';
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        $sel = $k==$current ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
        $opts .= "<option value='$k'  $sel>$k $v</option>\n";

    }
    return $opts;
}



?>

<html>
<body>
<br/>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
  <select name="site" onchange="this.form.submit();">
<?php echo"<option>Select Site</option>";?>
    <?php echo get_options($site_array);?>

  </select>



</form>
<br/>

<p> Displaying all information for:<?php if(isset($_POST['site'])){echo $_POST['site'];} ?></p>



<div style="void:both;";></div>



<div class='table_holder'>
  <div class='table' style='height:100px; margin-right:20px;'>
    <table width='100%' align='center' id='table1' class='tablesorter'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Publication Title</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>



<?php while($rows1=mysqli_fetch_array($result_table1)){ ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $rows1['ART_TITEL']; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php } ?>

    </table>
  </div> 
</div> 


<br/><br/>
<div style="void:both;";></div>
<br/><br/>

<div class='table_holder'>
  <div class='table' style='height:200px;'>
    <table width='100%' align='center' id='table2' class='tablesorter'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Aspects</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

<?php while($rows2=mysqli_fetch_array($result_table2)){ ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $rows2['Aspect']; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php } ?>

    </table>
  </div> 
</div> 

<br/><br/>
<div style="void:both;";></div>
<br/><br/>

<div class='table_holder'>
  <div class='table' style='height:200px;'>
    <table width='100%' align='center' id='table3' class='tablesorter'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Question</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
<?php while($rows3=mysqli_fetch_array($result_table3)){ ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $rows3['Question']; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php } ?>

    </table>
  </div> 
</div> 






<?php include 'footer.php' ?>
```

Comment: That would be an excellent place to use a prepared statement instead of assuming that it's a valid integer.

Comment: Perfect example of sql injection vulnerability

Comment: Could it be that your "connect.php" file contains the code for connecting to the database? If so, are you sure that the problem does not already occur there? Might be helpful if you could post the content of it (of course without the credentials).

Comment: add `if(empty($post_pub)){echo 'something not right'; exit();}` to validate your post variable;

Comment: connect.php contents (details changed)
`<?php
$servername = "localhost"; 
$username = "user"; 
$password = "pw";
$database = "db";
?>

<?php 
// Create connection 
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
?> `

Comment: added the if statement suggested by ntaloveenti... returns 'something not right'

Comment: correction to above, $post_pub is empty to start with, it has not been set until a value is selected from the drop down. Perhaps I should set this as an empty value to start with? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are setting `$post_pub` to a string if it is not present, but comparing in subsequent statements as if it is numberic

```
$post_pub = isset($_POST['site']) ?: $_POST['site'] = ''
```

here `$post_pub` will be set to '' if it is not present in the POST

when you build the sql like this

```
$sqltable1="SELECT Publications.Pub_ID, Publications.ART_TITEL FROM `Publications` where Pub_ID=$post_pub";
```

the statement would look like

```
SELECT Publications.Pub_ID, Publications.ART_TITEL FROM `Publications` where Pub_ID=
```

where you would want something like

```
SELECT Publications.Pub_ID, Publications.ART_TITEL FROM `Publications`
```

or

```
SELECT Publications.Pub_ID, Publications.ART_TITEL FROM `Publications` where Pub_ID=''
```

or

```
SELECT Publications.Pub_ID, Publications.ART_TITEL FROM `Publications` where Pub_ID is null
```

You should also consider using a parameter in the query rather than string concatenation as the code you have leaves you open to sql injection attacks.

Comment: You could change the first line to use the null coalescing operator (`??`)

Comment: Thank you for explaining how to avoid injection attacks. $post_pub is an integer.

Comment: what do you expect the select statements (e.g. $sqltable1) to return when there is no POST variable?

Comment: They used to return empty tables, which was fine for this project. I guess an if statement would sort that out `if(!empty($_POST['site'])){make table}else{}`

Answer (score -1):

Check the short if condition. 
Seems, that should be:

```
$post_pub = isset($_POST['site']) ? $_POST['site'] : '';
```

Check this example:

```
$post_pub = isset($_POST['site']) ?: $_POST['site'] = '';
echo $post_pub; // empty string

$_POST['site'] = 'test';
$post_pub = isset($_POST['site']) ?: $_POST['site'] = '';
echo $post_pub; // true - 1
```

Are you serching in db, by 'true', or concrect id ?

Comment: What's the purpose of `$_POST['site'] = ''` here?

Comment: If I understand correctly it sets a default to $_POST, in php5 I used $post_pub=$_POST['site']; Php7 seems to have more checks. When the page loads there is no value, the user selects a 'site' from a drop down then the $SERVER['PHP_SELF']; submits the selected entry (see the first form after the body tag)

Comment: The syntax is wrong. A ternary operator assigns the value to either side of the colon based on if the expression to the left of the question mark. The proper syntax is `$post_pub = isset($_POST['site']) ? $_POST['site'] : '';`

Comment: Still doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: What are You excepting to have in: $_POST['site'] ?

Comment: Initially it is empty, but then an integer is selected from the first form drop down. If I set the default value as 1 then site 1 is displayed.
But the default value persists even if the value in the form is changed.